# Get distinct values of multiple columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple columns from which I want to collect the distinct values.
I can do it this way:

```
for c in columns:
   values = dataframe.select(c).distinct().collect()
```

But this takes a lot of time. Is there a way of doing it for all columns at the same time?

Comment: What would the result of such operation look like (if it is possible)?

Comment: That's an excellent question. :-)

Comment: what will be the output ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you run it for all the columns you want in one pass?

Comment: I don't know how.

Comment: `val newDF = df.select(<columns you want>).distinct`.  Distinct can still be pretty expensive, but once is almost certainly better than doing it multiple times.

Comment: This gives me only distinct records. I need the values from each individual column.

Answer (score 2):

Use `collect_set` to collect distinct values from `column` function.

Sample Data in `DataFrame`

```
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  2|  4|
|  1|  3|  2|
|  4|  3|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

Import required functions

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

`collect_set` function to collect distinct values in `column`

```
>>> columnExprs = map(lambda c: collect_set(col(c)).alias(c),df.columns)
```

Apply `columnExprs` in select

```
>>> df.select(*columnExprs).show()
+---------+------+---------+
|        a|     b|        c|
+---------+------+---------+
|[1, 2, 4]|[2, 3]|[2, 3, 4]|
+---------+------+---------+
```

Use `collect` function to collect result.

```
>>> df.select(*columnExprs).collect()
[Row(a=[1, 2, 4], b=[2, 3], c=[2, 3, 4])]
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I need. Thank you very much!